# How to prevent options Menu "More" Button from getting localized on android?

Tags: android

The options menu's "More" button gets localized automatically, while the rest of the app isn't localized.  The "More" button changes to "Mas" because the I picked "espanol" as my language.  How do I prevent the "More" button from getting localized?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it from getting localized?  I'd imagine thats not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the more button manually in your menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_previous"
    android:title="Previous"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_todays"
    android:title="Todays" 
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_day" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_next"
    android:title="Next" 
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />    

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_more"
    android:title="More" 
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more">
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_achievements"
                android:title="Achievements" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
                android:title="About" />        
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_date_picker"
                android:title="Goto Date" />                  
                <item android:id="@+id/menu_instructions"
                android:title="Instructions" />   
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_moreapps"
                android:title="More apps" />                                  
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_twitter"
                android:title="Tweet your score" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_visitwebsite"
                android:title="Visit Stealthcopter.com" /> 
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_solutions"
    android:title="Show Solutions" 
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"/>             
<item android:id="@+id/menu_quit"
    android:title="Quit" 
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"/>          
</menu>
```

Comment: Could anyone tell me what's the R.string of the "more" string by default?